# Comparar un numeros de un arraylist con un boton

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo 4 botones y un arraylist con numeros entre 1-4, lo que necesito hacer es ir comparando los numeros del array con el boton que apreto (boton 1, boton 2, boton 3, boton 4) si es correcto que siga al siguiente numero sino que llame a la siguiente activity, estuve intentando y no lo logro hacerlo.

pd:utilizo android studio.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (a = 0; a < list.size(); a++) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.b1:
                p = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.b2:
                p = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.b3:
                p = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.b4:
                p = 4;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (list.get(a) == p) {
        iniciarTimer();
    }
    else{
        encender=false;
        fin();
    }
}
```

Eso fue lo ultimo que hice,en el caso que sea b1 p=1 y comparo con lo que tengo en la lista  y lo mismo con los otros 3 botones.

La idea del programa es que se genera un numero aleatorio entre 1 y 4, se prende ese boton y luego yo tengo que presionar ese boton, si es correcto se genera uno nuevo y se prenden el primer boton y el nuevo, presionar esos 2 botones si es correcto se genera otro y sigue (es el juego de mesa simon si es que lo conocen)

**Edit:** Dejo lo último que acabo de hacer, problema que tengo funciona todo bien hasta el if, cuando necesito que vuelva a iniciar el timer(el timer se inicia despues llama al `onClick` y cuando termina el `onClick` vuelve a llamar a iniciar timer)

Comment: Y el código?? Has avanzado algo??

Comment: agrega el còdigo que realizaste!

Comment: ahi subi el proceso que hice, es lo que se me ocurrio y habia probado con otra forma el otro dia y tampoco me funciono

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?